# Select(mark) & right click paste feature (like on cisco's IOS) on linux (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, copy-paste

Is it possible to make/enable/config bash on linux to be able to copy content from terminal by just selecting it and to paste by right click (like when you connect to switch/router with ssh)?

Answer (score 1):

Yep it is in fact it's on by default in most terminals see below for example. Ctrl-Shift-C & Ctrl-Shift-V are also very helpful in this regard. I'm using konsole in KDE but gnome-terminal and nearly every other terminal has this ability.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without X/Gnome/KDE: if you install `gpm` you can use your mouse for copy/mark and paste on console.